# Why are these style links coming in my angular material app head section

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using yeoman to build an angular app and have installed angular material via bower, when i am running the app i am getting about 15 style links what are all these most of them are those which i am not using in my app.

Here is the screenshot of app and head section:

[image: head section with styles]

Answer (score 0):

You can check (and post here) what selectors are in those style clocked, and than know which component generates it.